# $wpdb->last_error doesn't show the query on error

Tags: wpdb, errors

I am inserting data in the custom table using the `$wpdb->insert`. However, upon error I don't seem to get any information from `$wpdb->last_error`. What could be the cause of this?

I already have this configuration set in `wp-config`

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

The code is as below:

```
$result = $wpdb->insert($this->table, $data_);
if (false === $result) {
   error_log($wpdb->last_error);
}
```

`$this->table` and `$data_` are populated correctly as it runs successfully.
But I don't seem to get any information on the query that is failed. Is there any way I can get the actual query ran in `$wpdb->insert`?

**Solution**

OK so I figured out the problem. Insert query was failing because one of the column data was huge and exceeding the column size of the database. The column was `varchar(500)` but the actual data was more then 500 characters, thus failing the query. I changed the column to `TEXT` and insert was successful without errors.

Comment: Same problem as you, as your solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want the *query*, that'll be `$wpdb->last_query` (note that you also do not need `SAVEQUERIES`, that's only if you want a log of *every* query (`$wpdb->queries`)

`last_error` is... well, the error!

**Update:** Possible explanation for `last_error` being empty - this is the source of `wpdb::query()`:

```
// If we're writing to the database, make sure the query will write safely.
if ( $this->check_current_query && ! $this->check_ascii( $query ) ) {
    $stripped_query = $this->strip_invalid_text_from_query( $query );
    // strip_invalid_text_from_query() can perform queries, so we need
    // to flush again, just to make sure everything is clear.
    $this->flush();
    if ( $stripped_query !== $query ) {
        $this->insert_id = 0;
        return false;
    }
}

// Redacted code

// Keep track of the last query for debug..
$this->last_query = $query;

$this->_do_query( $query );

// Redacted code

// If there is an error then take note of it..
if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
    $this->last_error = mysqli_error( $this->dbh );
} else {
    $this->last_error = mysql_error( $this->dbh );
}
```

In other words, WordPress seems to pre-emptively check the query and will abort if it deems it will fail - in this case you get your `return false` but no error will be set (since it was never sent to the MySQL server).

Comment: but why don't I still get anything in the last_error? insert query results in false which means something failed, but still doesn't contain anything in last_error? Wierd?

Comment: Updated answer with possible explanation.

Comment: So what is the best way to get this work? I mean always get something in last_error upon errors

Answer (score 2):

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32315

One of the columns inputs may be larger than the column is.
Wordpress detects this and will not even send the query to the DB.

The Diff there shows a patch for wp-db you can put in to get more information in the last_error message so it will not be empty.

[image]

Comment: This is truly a cool answer.  I've adapted your answer into a wp-content/db.php file so it can be easily and quickly dropped in place to persist a solution across WordPress upgrades.  [See here for gist and more details](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/373903/18358).

Comment: Oh neat thanks @BrianC I saw an email a little while back that this issue has a milestone of 5.6 now.

Comment: Looks like a core fix is proposed but missed out on 5.5 and I think 5.6. Here’s hoping, sigh.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$result = $wpdb->insert($this->table, $data_);
```

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately that doesn't work.  The problem is that the error is caused by wpdb code which actually just exits with false and doesn't set `last_error`.