# How to use $wpdb to delete in a custom table

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am having trouble finding a good resource on using the $wpdb function.

I am trying to delete a row from a custom table named: eLearning_progress

```
$removefromdb = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM eLearning_progress WHERE ID = '$user_id' AND module_id = '$singlecomparearrays_remove'" );
```

The row I would like to delete has the ID of '$user_id' and the 'module_id' of '$singlecomparearrays_remove'.

I have also tried:

```
$removefromdb = $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM eLearning_progress WHERE ID = ($user_id) AND module_id = ($singlecomparearrays_remove)" );
```

and then:

```
$removefromdb = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM eLearning_progress WHERE ID = %s AND module_id = %s", $user_id, $singlecomparearrays_remove));
```

Please try not to sigh too loudly at my attempts but I can't find a good guide on using the DELETE  command with variables in there too.
Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Have you read [the codex about `delete()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/delete/)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand it enough to get it to work with my variables. Would you be able to give me an example?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The best WP API solution for this goal is to use the [`delete()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/delete/) function to remove a row.

A small example, to delete the raw `ID` in the custom table `eLearning_progress`.

```php
$id = 0815;
$table = 'eLearning_progress';
$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ) );
```

But I can't see which raw you will delete in your table `eLearning_progress`? Maybe you enhance the question to understand it much better.

Answer (score 0):

It still possible that your sql is creating trouble even use `$wpdb->delete`
I found it useful using one of these approach:

1. call `$wpdb->show_errors();` [before](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/225176/89333) querying
2. [enable](https://www.wpoptimus.com/1832/debug-wpdb-database-queries/) debug mode with
    `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`
   on your **wp-config.php**

Answer (score 0):

Using This You can easily delete

```
$MailMetaKey = yourkey
$post_id = yourpostid

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE * FROM f0_postmeta WHERE meta_key = $MailMetaKey' and post_id = '$post_id' "));
```

Comment: That's not a lot different to the OP's examples that didn't work, except that you're using prepare(). What does prepare() do if you're not using the function's argument substitution?

Answer (score 0):

**This code not working, show an error. I'm tried**

Please look at this screenshot https://prnt.sc/M3DYH_EmHCtM

```
global $wpdb;

$id = $_REQUEST['delete'];

$table = 'custom_user_info';

$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ) );
```

**But when I'm using this code, It's working perfectly**

```
$db_config = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'develop');

$id = $_REQUEST['delete'];

$delete = "DELETE FROM custom_user_info WHERE id=$id";

$query = mysqli_query($db_config, $delete);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).